# I was trying to run the demo provided in github, but none of them were working. failed to get the assembly reference

Tags: c#, windows-10, mnist, onnx, windows-machine-learning

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LearningModelSession' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   MNIST_Demo  C:\Users\ansifmx\Downloads\Windows-Machine-Learning-master
>   (5)\Windows-Machine-Learning-master\Samples\MNIST\UWP\cs\mnist.cs

```
25  Active
```

**similar error with all namespace, references in windows.machinelearning.ai**
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning
tried all three demos provided...none worked

please advice new here

1. Tried everything on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-broken-references?view=vs-2015
2. Tried referring windows.ai.machinelearing.preview
3. Updated all reference nuggets
4. Reinstalled references
5. nuggets manager both the check points are slected are on allow nuggets to download missing plugins,
   6.moved to repos

Comment: Have you tried Restoring Nuget pakages?

Comment: Place code at your repository on system like C:\Projects\..(I get issue if I try to run from Download location due to admin rights issue, although I have restored nuget setting automatic)

Comment: tried all these

Answer (score 1):

After updating windows to 1809 build 17763 with the latest SDK 17763. I was able to run the demo.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the referenced Nuget packges are not getting restored.
Verify the settings at **Tools >> NuGet Package Manage >> Package Manager Settings** and make sure that it is set to download any missing package during build.

[image]

The exact setting may differ slightly based on the VS version you are using.